# Basic java algorithm giving me a nullpointerexception error?

Tags: java, algorithm, routes

```
public class chocolatecake
{
    int rows,cols;
    public chocolatecake(int r, int c)
    {
        rows = r;
        cols = c;
    }
    private String letterBlock[][];

    public void fillBlock(String str)
    {
        boolean hasExtra;
        int tracker=0;
        for(int y=0;y<rows;y++)
        {
            for(int x=0;x<cols;x++)
            {
                letterBlock[y][x] = str.substring(tracker, tracker+1);
                System.out.println(letterBlock[y][x]);
                tracker++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SO the point of this program is to take a string and put it into an array first in row major order and then in column major order with a different array size, but im stuck here where the compiler is saying nullpointerexception at line 21

```
letterBlock[y][x] = str.substring(tracker, tracker+1);
```

Comment: Java convention is clear -- your class should be camel-cased (`ChocolateCake`).  This has nothing to do with your immediate problem but it is something of which you should be aware.

Answer (score 1):

Allocate your string array in the constructor:

```
letterBlock = new String[r][c];
```

like this:

```
public chocolatecake(int r, int c)
{
    rows = r;
    cols = c;
    letterBlock = new String[r][c];

    // Not like this, it will create a local variable:
    // String letterBlock = new String[r][c];
}
private String letterBlock[][];
```

The other possible reason for a NullPointerException is if str is null. If it is not long enough you will get an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: I have put this code in the constructor but it doesn't seem right and I get an error. Could u explain where to allocate the string please?

Comment: @benrosenberg see edits, hope it clarifies it for you

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the array letterBlock.
e.g.

```
String letterBlock[][] = new String[10][2];
```

Answer (score 0):

your `rows` and `cols` are assume to be null, this in case you're not calling your `chocolatecake` function

Comment: they are in a constructor though...i have a tester class with numbers for the variables